# Clarifying the definition of node in Edwards and Penney

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, definition

In the 3rd edition of Edwards and Penney's *Elementary Differential Equations*, on page 513, I'm trying to nail down the definition of a "node" in general.  The text says:

"In general, the critical point $(x_0, y_0)$ of the autonomous system...is called a **node** provided that *either* every trajectory approaches $(x_0, y_0)$ as $t \rightarrow +\infty$, *or* every trajectory recedes from $(x_0, y_0)$ as $t \rightarrow +\infty$, *and* every trajectory is tangent at $(x_0, y_0)$ to some straight line through the critical point."

My questions are

First, is the sentence structure of that $(A \text{ or } B)$ and $C$, or is it $A$ or $(B \text{ and } C)$?  I suspect it is the former, but since I can't figure out the whole thing I am uncertain.

Second, what is the meaning of $C$, i.e. "every trajectory is tangent at $(x_0, y_0)$ to some straight line through the critical point."?  How does that even have a meaning?  Every curve has a tangent line if it is differentiable.  Is that simply a confusing way of saying the trajectories must be differentiable?  Or is there some other meaning I am missing?

I understand the material pretty well, but that little point eludes me.

Comment: The last condition excludes spiraling behavior and, as far as I can see, also non-isotropic behavior. Meaning that, in the regular case, the Jacobian at the node has to be a multiple of the unit matrix.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I don't see how spirals are excluded.  I don't see how ANYTHING is excluded, the condition looks just too general to be useful.